# Hyperledger Fabric - How CA works

Tags: certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, certificate-authority

I'm trying to understand how the Certification Authority (CA) manages the certificates of the users in Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.

**1 - Does the CA keep both the public and private keys or only the public one?**

And I have also another question related to the MSP.

**2- I have a "msp" folder which contains the following folders:**

- **cacerts**
- **intermediatecerts**
- **keystore**
- **signcerts**

**can anybody explain what are the certificates stored into them?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The Fabric CA issues and stores public keys only.  Private keys are generated and stored by the client prior to invoking the enroll API (which essentially generates a CSR - certificate signing request - and submits it to the Fabric CA which then issues a signed X509 certificate.

2) Have a look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/msp.html?highlight=MSP#msp-setup-on-the-peer-orderer-side for more details, but in short:

- `cacerts`  - hold the public key of the root authority which signs and issues certificates for this MSP (i.e. the root CA which issued the cert in signcerts below)
- `intermediatecerts` - optionally holds intermediate certificates which sign and issue certificates for the MSP (i.e. the intermediate CA which issued the cert in signcerts below)
- `signcerts` - the public signing key/certificate for a specific identity
- `keystore` - the private signing key for a specific identity